# CSS compression & combining / js minification - Better to do at runtime or at build time?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, css, caching, compression

I have to come up with a solution to compress, version (for caching purposes) and potentially combine our JS and CSS files and I've seen two dominant approaches so far:

1) At build time: As an MSBuild task or similar.
2) Dynamically at run time: As a custom HTTPHandler (we are ASP.NET btw) for .js and .css files, with something like this ending up in your pages:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/StyleSheetHandler.ashx?stylesheets=~stylesheets/master.css" />
```

Can anyone provide information of pro's and con's of each? Personally, I can't see the point of doing it dynamically and wasting CPU cycles at the time of each request (I guess you'd only do with the work first time and then cache, but still) but I get the feeling I might be missing something?

Thanks!
Mark.

Comment: Will be turning on GZIP anyway, but combining/versioning/minifying are separate.

Comment: Here's what I cranked out: http://www.markgibaud.com/blog/?p=22

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think a good approach is to use different strategies for different environments:

- *no* compression for *development* (for developing & debugging)
- *runtime* compression for *test environment* (flexible, not performance-critical)
- *buildtime* compression for *staging and production* (tested, performance-critical)

I have some experience using the [YUI compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) for both Javascript and CSS and have learned (the hard way) that testing minified JS and CSS is indeed very important.

Creating static minified JS and CSS files as part of your build for production has the following benefits:

- they are tested
- static files, can be served without ASP.NET overhead
- can be browser cached
- should be webserver-gzipped

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to *not do it at all*, since all modern browsers and servers handle Gzip encoding. Look at the numbers:

- cfform.js - 21k
- cfform-minified.js - 12k
- cfform.js.gz - 4.2k
- cfform-minified.js.gz - 2.2k

This is a fairly large JS file with plenty of unnecessary whitespace but in the final equation you've saved a whopping 2k !! Not only that but thanks to caching this saving is per-visitor, not per-page. Whoo-hoo, now that was worth all the trouble wasn't it?

You'd save 10 times that by cropping a pixel width off the top of your banner and with 99% of your users on broadband you've saved them about 1 millisecond of download time. Break out the streamers and champagne!

JS compression is even worse, since you've just hit your clients with the burden of decompressing on EVERY PAGE LOAD. And the savings after gzip are just as miserable.

Seriously. The added complexity and debugging is not worth it unless you are targetting a mobile market (and even that assumes the users are still on CDMA, not 3G) or have a billion hits per day. Otherwise just don't bother.

Comment: Once again downvoted by someone who fails to understand the issue. That's my one gripe with SO, even idiots can vote.

Comment: Well, @SpliFF, I can understand that just enabling gzip is easier and prone to less hassles, but what about concatenation of files and obfuscation of javascript? Concatenation could mean a single file being sent and decompressed, and regarding obfuscation, some businesses like to have their JS code hard to read.

Comment: Concatenation and obfuscation are overrated. In the typical case the files you'll want to compress the most are libraries like jquery/prototype and they are already minified and hosted on CDNs. You'll also end up with a conflict between serving only the scripts you need on a given page or all the scripts on your site regardless of relevance to the page you're on. Obfuscation does very little to protect code. Valuable code will typically take months or years to write and about a day to de-obsfucate. People who think it'll stop their code being stolen are only fooling themselves.

Comment: Even browsers on a 5+Mbit line have quite a lag setting up each http request and simultaneous requests are limited. In scenario's with 20+ JS and 10+ CSS files (try DNN, WordPress, Joomla with two dozen plugins) this lag is very noticeable. In a real-world scenario, I used gzip + minify to go from 1030kB to 650kB (incl imgs), no big deal and little change in rendering. Then I added bundling of JS/CSS and render time increased up to 3 times as fast. Pages that were hardly usable before, suddenly became a pleasure to work with. In the end, it is all about improving user experience.

Comment: @Abel: Yeah, for the first page and only if all JS and CSS comes from the same server (browsers will parallel requests to multiple domains). After that local caching kicks in rendering network issues moot. You still aren't getting bang for your buck when you consider the issues that concatenation can cause and how hard it is to debug and fix issues with it. Spend the same amount of time optimising any other aspect of your pages and you'll get better results.

Comment: _"After that local caching kicks in rendering network issues moot." >>>_ not quite. The server still needs to roundtrip and wait for a 304 response. Also, many sites have unique, non-recurring visitors. On my example (a DNN site), increase of rendering speed went from sluggish to responsive, even after a primed cache. Considering that configuring minifying and bundling takes a few minutes (.NET 4.5, Apache servers with mod_pagespeed, DNN 6+) it's a no-brainer. A suggestion: read "High performance web sites", a classic on the subject by Steve Sounders.

Comment: _"how hard it is to debug and fix issues with it" >>_ not anymore. Only enable minification when `debug="false"` (most out-of-the-box minify/bundle libraries do this by default). The technique iself has matured over the last five years (see ASP.NET 3.5/4.0 auto-bundling for AJAX, which when disabled, makes an insane difference in performance, mod_pagespeed and, third party libs like http://requestreduce.org/).

Comment: @Abel: A 304 response round-trip is NOT required for static javascript and css. You set an expires header a day or two in the future and no check is required until it expires. Your debugging claims are false as well. Those debug flags disable minification, they don't help you at all when the minification itself fails or causes side-effects.

Comment: @Abel: I can tell you flat out there isn't a single browser that will re-request a resource with a future expiry date unless you force it to or you have conflicting headers. You're spreading false information.

Comment: I stand corrected on the 304 info, my test itself was wrong (the 304's I saw were near-future and had just passed). I've removed my previous comment to not bug others with it. But regardless, imo the effort of minification and bundling remains worth it for several reasons that have been discussed over and over in books and forums. It simply makes your site more responsive and it cut down on my bandwidth costs with 40% or so. Oh, and really, never try to debug a minified file, just throw it away. Really.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say its better to do on first request and cache. the reason for this is so that you can update the css as needed in a readable format without having to go back to rebuilding. you can base your cache on the css file so as soon as it is changed the cache refreshes.

Josh

Answer (score 1):

You do it at runtime but only when you need to. This gives you the most flexibility. It's particularly an issue with PHP which otherwise has no build step (ie you don't want to add one when you don't have one otherwise) but still an issue for other platforms that do.

At the risk of self-promotion, you might want to read [Supercharging Javascript in PHP](http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/05/supercharging-javascript.html) and [Supercharging CSS in PHP](http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/05/supercharging-css-in-php.html), which outline the issues, approaches and best practices. The examples are in PHP but the code itself is trivial. The issues and principles apply to any Web platform.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make it at run time, except if your CSS and JS files are really huge (more than 1MB). 
The browser cache can be force by setting a few [http headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers), and when you want your application to force a reload at the client side, just change an HTTP param :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/StyleSheetHandler.ashx?stylesheets=~stylesheets/master.css&token=1" />
```

You can change the token to force the reload of the CSS at client side.